# Calling GWT Web Application into android

Tags: gwt

how to use the gwt web application in to android.Can anybody help me?How to write the listener ?Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you want to develop mobile apps/websites using gwt, read the article [GWT Support for Mobile App Development](http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2012/07/gwt-support-for-mobile-app-development.html) that describes mgwt as a library for developing mobile apps and mobile websites with GWT using a single codebase.

[The steps can be :](http://lehelsipos.blogspot.com/2012/08/mgwt-very-simple-example-click-button.html)

1. Create a GWT project
2. add this line to `.gwt.xml`

`<inherits name='com.googlecode.mgwt.MGWT'/>`

1. [Download](http://code.google.com/p/mgwt/downloads/list) and add the mgwt library to your project.
2. Modify your `EntryPoint` as you like.

`public class MobileEntryPoint implements EntryPoint {`

```
int countI;
MTextBox lbl;

public void onModuleLoad() {
    lbl = new MTextBox();
    countI = 0;

    MGWT.applySettings(MGWTSettings.getAppSetting());
    AnimationHelper animationHelper = new AnimationHelper();
    RootPanel.get().add(animationHelper);
    LayoutPanel layoutPanel = new LayoutPanel();
    Button button = new Button("Hello mgwt!");

    button.addTapHandler(new TapHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onTap(TapEvent event) {
            countI++;
            lbl.setText("You clicked: " + countI + " times");
        }
    });
    layoutPanel.add(button);
    layoutPanel.add(lbl);

    animationHelper.goTo(layoutPanel, Animation.SLIDE);
}
```

`}`

Go through [HelloWorld Example](http://code.google.com/p/mgwt/wiki/HelloWorldExample) and [Running Showcase](http://code.google.com/p/mgwt/wiki/RunningShowcase) by Daniel Kurka as well.

Answer (score 0):

[MGwt??](http://www.m-gwt.com/)
          --->Making GWT work with mobile

To use mgwt you need to download the latest release and put it in your classpath. After that you have to include it in your gwt.xml file. You can also set the user agent property for gwt to safari, because almost any mobile device runs on webkit and `mgwt` relies on `webkit`.

**Usage:**

```
<inherits name="com.googlecode.mgwt.MGWT"/>
<set-property name="user.agent" value="safari" />
```

Also reffer [GWT Phonegap](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-phonegap/wiki/GettingStarted)

Comment: Link only answers aren't good answers. Please can you include the relevant parts of the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

A gwt app in android should almost work because its browser is webkit based, which is supported in gwt, so simply try to open your app from your android browser.

A different thing is that certain widgets could behave weird because of screen size or because they are thought for mouse events (this is the case of drag and drop), so maybe for certain panels you have to consider to program touch-events which are supported in the gwt events mechanism.

If you wanted your app look different in mobile than in web there are some 3party libraries specific for mobile like [mgwt](http://www.m-gwt.com) which makes your app looks like a native mobile app. Mgwt even adds more permutations so as you could have different web views for different target devices. Other libraries you could be interested on could be [gwtmobile-ui](https://github.com/dennisjzh/GwtMobile-UI) or [sencha](http://www.sencha.com) mobile.

Finally, if you want your webapp be embedded in an android package, you need Apache cordova (aka phonegap). There is a gwt library to access certain features cordova has (hardware calls like open camera, filesystem, etc) it is called [gwt-phonegap](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-phonegap/)